# read database visual foxpro from webservice developed c#

Tags: c#, oledb, foxpro, dbf

I'm trying to read a foxpro table from a web service developed in C # and a 64bit server, but when opening the table the error:

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: **External table is not in the expected format.**
to do this use the microsoft.ace12 provider.}

unfortunately I can not use oledb 32 bit on a 64 bit server.

any idea ..
sorry for my bad English;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [read dbf file from web service developed with c # using microsoft.ace12 version 64 bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954424/read-dbf-file-from-web-service-developed-with-c-using-microsoft-ace12-version)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the 32bit VFP OLE-DB driver on a 64bit machine.  Then look at the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717/why-doesnt-vfp-net-oledb-provider-work-in-64-bit-windows)

Comment: Correct... VFP does not utilize 64-bit and the user should be using the specific "VFP OleDB" provider directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Application pool that this Web Service is using to use 32bit. But if you're using MS Access Connectivity Engine driver - there's a 64bit version of it.